# Hitchhikers Guide to Calculus. (Spivak) Typo or real?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

A quick and very silly question. On page 56 Spivak is working his way to "instantaneous velocity" with an example of a ball dropping from a height. We are given the formula $s(t) = 16t^2$ where $t$ is time, and $s(t)$ is 'distance traveled'. As a first step he calculates the 'average velocity' at time $t_0$ if the ball had travelled $1$ additional second.

$$ \begin{aligned} \textsf {average velocity}    &=  \frac{16(t_0 + 1)^2 - 16t_0^2} {1}\\ &= \frac{16t_0^2 + 32t_0 + 1 - 16t_0^2} {1} \\ &= 32t_0 + 1  \end{aligned} $$

By my calculation, the answer should be $$\begin{aligned}&=32t_0 + 16\end{aligned}$$

But, he gives 2 more examples (with different values) , but each follows the same pattern, so I'm guessing it is not an error. How does he end up with $32t_0 + 1$? What am I missing? Thanks.

For completeness, he arrives at this formulation, now taking a very small time interval $h$.

$$ \begin{aligned} \textsf {average velocity}    &=  \frac{16(t + h)^2 - 16t^2} {h}\\ &= \frac{16t^2 + 32ht + h^2 - 16t^2} {h} \\ &= \frac{32ht + h^2} {h} \\ &= 32t + h \end{aligned} $$

Comment: Can you show your derivation?

Comment: Appears to be a typo in my opinion...

Comment: $16(t+1)^2=16t^2+32t+16.$  Has all the signs of an error followed by a copying of the error...

Comment: @abiessu  That sounds like the most likely scenario. In the end, of course, it does not really effect the outcome, but it's unexpected.

Comment: In summary, you are correct. That was (surprisingly) sloppy algebra on Spivak’s part.

Comment: Any chance everyone in the writing and editing teams were distracted looking for the H2G2 joke ("tea and not tea") with "not $t$ and $t$ nought"?

Comment: Unfortunately (Spivak...) I must confirm that the same error is on page 57.